# Using ARG for substitution causes `docker run` to fail

Tags: docker

I've been struggling with issues after adding the `ARG` statement into our Dockerfile.

I'm using the the following command to run the Docker image:
`docker run -d -p <PORT>:<PORT>/tcp --name <NAME> <IMAGE>`

Original Dockerfile. This starts without issue:

```
FROM golang:1.14                     

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

ADD server.bin /app/server.bin
ADD base/config /app/base/config

CMD "/app/server.bin"
```

The modified Dockerfile is supposed to allow `BINARY_NAME` values via the `ARG` keyword.

```
FROM golang:1.14                                

ARG BINARY_NAME

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

ADD $BINARY_NAME /app/$BINARY_NAME
RUN chmod +x /app/$BINARY_NAME   # Adding this line gives the same error.
ADD base/config /app/base/config

CMD "/app/$BINARY_NAME"
```

This modified Dockerfile fails to start with:
`/bin/sh: 1: /app/: Permission denied`

Tried the following without avail:

- Running `docker event&` and `docker start -a ...` for a more verbose output, but there is no additional information, aside from the fact that the container is starting and dying.
- Enclosing substitutions in curly braces.
- Adding `RUN chmod +x`.

Does anyone know what is going on here, for the `ARG` statement to throw permission issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Dockerfile like below:

```sh
FROM golang:1.14                                

ARG BINARY_NAME

# Make `BINARY_NAME` an environment variable so that `CMD` can use it
ENV BINARY_NAME=$BINARY_NAME

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080

ADD $BINARY_NAME /app/$BINARY_NAME
RUN chmod +x /app/$BINARY_NAME
ADD base/config /app/base/config

CMD "/app/$BINARY_NAME"
```